# Cannot call external javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function, external

I cannot call the function clickie from the file fair_functions.js

html page

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="fair_functions.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" onclick="clickie();"</script>">Next</button>

</body>
```

fair_functions.js

```
function clickie () {

alert("asdfsadfsdf");
window.open('test (2).html','_blank');
self.close();
```

}

Comment: The </script> in the button defenition is not supposed to be there.

Comment: Modify  <button type="button" onclick="clickie();"</script>">Next</button> to  <button type="button" onclick="clickie();">Next</button>

Comment: I have that... it just doesnt grab the function.

Comment: Is `fair_functions.js` in the same directory as the html page?

Comment: what does console tell you? do you have errors?

Comment: are you certain that your external script file is loading? check your network tab to confirm.

Comment: scrappedcola - I dont have console... I'm just writing it in a js file, then trying to use it in an html file.

Comment: fgshepard - What do you mean network tab?

Comment: try running it in Chrome and take a look at this:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index
 it will make your life much easier. similar tools are available in most browsers.

Comment: a quick way to determine if you file is downloading would be to move the alert outside of your function body. just put it at the top of your external file. if it doesn't run on page load, then you have a problem. either javascript is off or you're not getting that file.

Comment: If you are running this code in a browser that is IE/Firefox/Chrome/etc you have a developer tools. Your first place to debug issues is there. If you have firefox download firebug extension. In the other browsers hit f12. There is your element viewer and console. If you have Chrome/firefox you will also have a network tab. Use your tools and you will have an easier time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the script in the body and just before the `</body>` tag e.g.

```
...

<script src="fair_functions.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Arent you supposed to tell it the source in the head so it knows where the function is coming from?

Comment: No, in the `head` leave only jQuery/jQueryUI if you use it, every other script put just before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, I just created a new file and copied in my functions one at a time and tested each time. It seems to be working now, not sure what happened in the old file.

Comment: reading the discussion above, I suspect you using badly suited tools (like windows, notepad, IE, etc.) and you had a hidden ".js.txt" ending messing up the path or something like that.

Comment: I'm using sublime text.. but there wasnt any hidden file extensions. I checked almost everything I could.